# SSH connection from gcloud instance to local machine

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I want to connect from the google cloud machine to my computer using SSH but I get this error.

```
ssh filename username@ip:path_to_save_file_on_my_computer
```

**ssh: connect to host 10.180.x.x port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection**

Comment: It is probably firewalled.

Comment: @Max so what is the solution ?

Comment: Well, 10.180.x.x is in the private use area, so you're not going to be able to ssh to that.  You first need your real IP and make sure that any port forwarding necessary is done.  So, you have a lot of fundamental networking problems to fix first.  It's way easier to to ssh from a private IP then to it.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you trying to connect from local machine to an instance which would be the normal case. Let me know if you are looking for a different scenario.

You can connect to instances that do not have external IP addresses by following any method from the [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#sshbetweeninstances)
.

Additionally keep in mind that your Google Cloud Platform VPC network must have one or more firewall rules that allow SSH connections on port 22. The [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) must allow SSH connections for the IP ranges or specific IP addresses from which you want to connect.

In case your GCE VM does have an external IP, I would recommend connecting using ["gcloud compute SSH"](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance), since once [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) has been [setup](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/login), it will create automatically the necessary keys to access the VMs.